# jquery product builder

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to build this interface using jQuery. I originally did it in Flash. http://www.allprocustomtrailers.com/

It allows the customer to customize the trailer to thier needs and proceed to another page to view the list than email it to the sales force. I've been searching online for hours for the last 2 days on just how to get started on this. I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there is already a base available to build off of in HTML5 that would be great. My jQuery skills a intermediate at best so this is my big project to shove me into the deep end. I just don't want to drowned.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm at a stalemate as to how to even start. Looking for something I can analyze like a tutorial that touches on the basics of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: you can do that without jquery, just little js and css

Answer (score 3):

This could easily be done without the use of JQuery as well.

To re-create this application in Javascript/HTML/CSS, you'll likely be heavily relying on the [`"OnClick"` attribute of elements](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/event-attributes/onclick). This will allow you to execute a snippet of Javascript whenever that given element (likely styled as a button) is clicked. JQuery does have a method of [binding actions to click events](http://api.jquery.com/click/), but for someone who is relatively new to JQuery (and the method I personally prefer) is the `OnClick` attribute.

Here is a basic implementation of the `OnClick` functionality that I think would help you re-create your application.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function update_form(selection){
        document.getElementById("preview").src = selection + ".jpg";
        document.getElementById("formdata").value = selection;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span OnClick="update_form('option1');">Click here for Option 1.</span><br />
    <span OnClick="update_form('option2');">Click here for Option 2.</span><br />
    <img src="blank.jpg" id="preview" /><br />
    <form action="submit.php" action="post">
      <input type="text" name="selectionvalue" id="formdata"><br />
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: This gives me a directions in which to proceed. I will test this out next week and I'm sure be back with more questions. Thank you.